# Function into fragment stop refreshing after change tab

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an app with 2 tabs where the first include somes values which are refreshed during the time. I take these values from a `PhoneStateListener` activity and I transfer them into the fragment with the function below. The problem is, when I move to 2nd tab and after that move back to first the values are not refresed anymore.

```
public void test(int LteSignalStrength,int LteRsrp,int LteRsrq,int LteRssnr,int LteCqi){
    if(ntype=="\nNetwork Type: LTE\n"){
        tv2.setText("\nLteSignalStrength:"+dbm+" dbm"+
                "\nLteRsrp: "+LteRsrp+
                "\nLteRsrq: "+LteRsrq+
                "\nLteRssnr: "+LteRssnr);
    }
}
```

PhonestateListener Activity

```
public Tab1Signal(Tab1Values fragment){
    mcontext = fragment.getContext();
    main=fragment;
}   

public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength){
    super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
    try {
        Method[] methods = android.telephony.SignalStrength.class.getMethods();
        for (Method mthd : methods) {
            if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteSignalStrength")){
                //val1=mthd.getName() ;
                LteSignalStrength=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                //main.test(val2);
            }
            if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRsrp")){
                LteRsrp=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
            }
            if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRsrq")){
                LteRsrq=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
            }
            if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRssnr")){
                LteRssnr=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
            }
            if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteCqi")){
                LteCqi=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
            }
            main.test(LteSignalStrength,LteRsrp,LteRsrq,LteRssnr,LteCqi);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Does anyone know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass listener in method `onTabChanged` when tab contain `Tab1Signal`